# Перемещение выбранного элемента в ListBox

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Есть listBox1, и там есть свойство

```
listBox1.SelectedItem
```

Я выбрал нужное значение, и теперь мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выделился предыдущий элемент в listBox'e, ниже скриншоты

[image]

У меня сейчас выделена строка "Яхта", я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку со строки "Яхта" выбранная строка перешла на "Самолет".

Comment: Заголовок должен отражать смысл вопроса.

Comment: Извините, просто я не всегда могу его подобрать :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте начать с этого [ListBox.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло! :=)

Comment: Хорошо, что всё получилось.